# How do i solve this problem? vscode blue lines

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

#Pls_Help
How Can I solve this VS CODE problem? is there any way to get fresh editor? how can i remove these blue lines? It's so annoying! [bluelines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHv20.png)

Comment: add const to text to be like this    child : const Text()

Answer (score 0):

Add const before the text like this:

```
title: const Text()
```